# How to Infer Generic Property Types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I can't figure out how to infer the type of a generic property based on the generic type of the object it's on. In the following example, how can I say that `Something.aProp` needs to match the type of Something's `U.obj.prop`?

```
interface Prop {
  a: number;
}
interface FancyProp extends Prop {
  b: number;
}

interface Obj<T extends Prop> {
  prop: T;
}

interface FancyObj extends Obj<FancyProp> {}

interface Parent<T extends Obj<any>> { // <-- the <any> here seems wrong too
  obj: T;
}

interface FancyParent extends Parent<FancyObj> {
  fancy: number;
}

class Something<U extends Parent<any>> {
  aProp: typeof U.obj.prop;
}
```

I.e. `Something<Parent>.aProp` should be of type `Prop`, and `Something<FancyParent>.aProp` is of type `FancyProp`?

Comment: You want [lookup types, aka indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#keyof-and-lookup-types), like `U['obj']['prop']`

Comment: Can you explain `the <any> here seems wrong too`?  What specifically is your issue there?

Comment: By `<any> here seems wrong` I mean that the type constraint on Obj should be inferred based on the generic type `T` on `Parent`

Comment: Well, you can write `Obj<Prop>` if you want, which will be a bit more type safe, but depending on your actual non-example interfaces you might need to resort to `any` unless you want `Parent` to have multiple generic parameters as in `Parent<P extends Prop, T extends Obj<P>>`

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the comments! By adding type constrained versions of the plain (non-fancy) interfaces, I seem to be able to use lookup types and only a single type parameter to the class:

```class Something<T extends Parent<any>> {
  aProp: T['obj']['prop'];
}

interface PlainObj extends Obj<Prop> {}
interface PlainParent extends Parent<PlainObj> {}

new Something<PlainParent>().aProp.a;
new Something<FancyParent>().aProp.b;```

Comment: The formatting on that is broken, but my question is answered. @jcalz do you want the points?

Comment: Heh, probably... I'll write up an answer when I get the chance.  If I don't make it in time, others should feel free to write it up in my absence.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your main question, the way to look up the type of a property value given an object type `T` and a key type `K` is to use [lookup types, a.k.a., indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#keyof-and-lookup-types), via the bracket syntax `T[K]`.  So if you want to look up the type of the `"prop"`-keyed property of the `"obj"`-keyed property of an object of type `U`, you would write that type as `U["obj"]["prop"]`.

Note that dot syntax doesn't work for types, even if the key types are string literals.  It would be nice if `U.obj.prop` were a synonym for `U["obj"]["prop"]` in the type system, but [unfortunately that syntax would collide with namespaces](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30267#issuecomment-470797283), since there could be a namespace named `U`, with a subnamespace named `obj`, with an exported type named `prop`, and then `U.obj.prop` would refer to that type.

---

For your comments about `any`, it's not really *wrong* to use `X extends Y<any>` when `Y<T>`'s type parameter `T` has a [generic constraint](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), but it might be a bit less type safe than you can get.  If the type `Y<T>` is related to `T` in a [covariant](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) way, then you can use the generic constraint instead of `any`.

That would mean, for example, `Parent<T extends Obj<any>>` could be replaced with `Parent<T extends Obj<Prop>>`, and `U extends Parent<any>` could be replaced with `U extends Parent<Obj<Prop>>`.

---

Those changes give you code like this:

```
interface Parent<T extends Obj<Prop>> {
    obj: T;
}

class Something<U extends Parent<Obj<Prop>>> {
    aProp: U['obj']['prop'];
    constructor(u: U) {
        this.aProp = u.obj.prop;
    }
}
```

I also added a constructor to `Something` because [class properties should be initialized](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#strict-class-initialization) and I wanted to show that `aProp` could be assigned with a value from `u.obj.pop` when `u` is a `U`.

And this should work as you expect:

```
interface PlainObj extends Obj<Prop> { }
interface PlainParent extends Parent<PlainObj> { }
new Something<PlainParent>({ obj: { prop: { a: 1 } } }).aProp.a; // number

interface FancyObj extends Obj<FancyProp> { }
interface FancyParent extends Parent<FancyObj> {
    fancy: number;
}
new Something<FancyParent>({ obj: { prop: { a: 1, b: 2 } }, fancy: 3 }).aProp.b; // number
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAdkG8CwAUMicnAFzIgCuAtgEbQDcRAvkaJLIigGJwgEAT3TZkEAB6QQAEwDOaTDgLFS9SjQbM2RDuGjwkyAPL0AVgB4AKuKkRZC0VgB8eIqWRYllKy0LtCTgMeNDgoezBrW2l5E3MLJ2dXFQ8Mcx8-AKIEABs4OQUAZQxaCDAAC1AAcwsAVWj7WNQwiItTS0Skt1USOCdKWoBtAHI0s2GAXRGvbEm-DwQMEDkwKGoEMAwoAApqAYBKPGR3D1IK4DkAOj6lZABeZGpLscuZrHnSAKzA-W4jVDyoHaDQccQ6SmSyACQT+KABcFAzXC4BBTRa4ASgJA7UhARAEAA7shiqVziAavDEeiwM5trhkGNKPS3kyyJQAIxQrmsfbXJzXJjIAD0QqodEYUF0Py4hj4AmEwMkMQU7Qs-EEIghR2hv1lyHVwiREVRjmpavlQhx3Q88A1GnF2n8RHxRJJZUq5PNGqN4Fp9MZRxZRwoyHZABpkOpkAAmbkR23CSgAZihvJu2Eu9EFIrFWigQA)